# Get selected / highlighted text in Google docs from a chrome extension in Mac and Windows OS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-docs, textselection

The goal is to **get the highlighted text** when a user selects text in Google docs like this:
[image]

Since `window.getSelection()` doesn't work in Google doc, they expose `docs-texteventtarget-iframe` element to render user selected text

And here is the code am using to get the text:

```
const iframe = document.querySelector(".docs-texteventtarget-iframe")
const selectedText = iframe.contentDocument.getSelection().toString()
console.log(selectedText)
```

But Mac and Windows with chrome version ( 105.0.5195.102 ), the iframe doesn't render the selected text. Therefore the above code returns empty string `" "`.

[image]

In ubnuntu chrome version 105.0.5195.102 ( same version ) the selected text gets rendered in the iframe element:

[image]

And `iframe.contentDocument.getSelection().toString()` returns *A man is standing in the middle of a road.*

**Any reason why it only works in Chrome running in Ubnutu?**

Answer (score 1):

I think you want Google Apps Script "getSelection()"

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getSelection()

There are some others functions that deal with selections and ranges on that page.

I guess the point is you have to use the google docs API, not the HTLM DOM ( Document Object Model ).

Comment: But can I use docs API from extension content script?

Answer (score 1):

i try to figure this, and i saw google docs using canvas for display [data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext).

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.kix-canvas-tile-content').forEach(ll => {
    ll.onselect = function () { myselection() };
})
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work @iam